# javaagent FileTransformer with ASM donesn't work

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

My FileTransformer doesn't work well. I've made it simple.

Here It is `premain`

```
public class App {
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        inst.addTransformer(new MyFirstFileTransformer());
        System.out.println("first-agent premain");
    }
}
```

and `FileTransformer`
public class MyFirstFileTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer{

```
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    System.out.println("entering trsnform");
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
    System.out.println("entering ClassReader");
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
    System.out.println("ClassWriter");
    System.out.println("??? what?");
    return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Simple is that. I 've made a `jar` file by maven.

My `test` class is in a different project.

```
public class ComplicatedObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("main");
    }
}
```

And The output is funny.

```
first-agent premain
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
main
entering trsnform
entering trsnform
```

I've tested my code in the same project. It works fine but after divide in two. It doesn't work. Please help!!

Comment: You are using ASM, hence triggering the loading of a bunch of classes from that library and your transformer is invoked again for each of them. You should use the provided `className` argument to skip classes that you can't handle without creating a circular dependency.

Comment: Thank you for comment. But my question is even [transform] method works but doesn't ender ClassReader nor ClassWriter. other print methods don't work.

Comment: Did you understand that when you do `new ClassReader`, the class `ClassReader` gets loaded and your transformer in invoked with that class? Just let your first print statement print the contents of the `className` parameter and think about what you see…